# Folium Heatmaps

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, folium

**Heatmaps in Folium**

I have a dataframe with house transactions data (metadata about the house, location and price).

I would like to make a heatmap in folium representing the price, and not the frequency as per default. So, areas with high transaction prices gets more colored and vice versa.

Do anybody know? My best guess would be to represent the price as as number of rows, e.g. if one row was one price unit and the house was sold for 5 units, then I would need to duplicate the row 5 times. But this is simply not compute friendly enough (if at all possible).

Thanks!

Here is a representation of my data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"house_id" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     "latitude": [55.83, 55.79, 55.86, 55.85],
                     "longitude": [12.05, 12.10, 12.07, 12.09],
                     "price": [2000, 2100, 1500, 4500]})
```

And here comes the code I use to generate the heatmap with Folium, which by now makes the "heat" in terms of how frequent the location apperars in terms of #rows..

```
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

heat_data = [[row['latitude'],row['longitude']] for index, row in data.iterrows()]
map = folium.Map(location=[55.838913, 12.055415], zoom_start = 13)

# Plot it on the map
HeatMap(heat_data).add_to(map)

# Display the map
map
```

Comment: Please, provide your code and data. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @sentece. I have provided data and code now.

Comment: I do not think heatmap is the right solution. Maybe you need to choose another way to visualize your information. If you want to visualize information per row, maybe you should do simple things with markers. Otherwise, you should go with some kind of clustering, in order to group information and then visualize it by a choropleth map.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right @sentence. Markers could be working out with prober use of alpha and color codes for binned and ordinal price-range categories.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Import the Lib
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

#Make the list of Lat an Lng
lat = data.latitude.tolist()
lng = data.longitude.tolist()

#Create the Map
map = folium.Map(
    location=[55.838913, 12.055415],
    tiles='cartodbdark_matter',
    zoom_start=11
)
HeatMap(list(zip(lat, lng))).add_to(map)
map
```